# Ubuntu 14.04.02 Vs Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.04, 14.10

I am straight forward asking this question. Why shouldn't I upgrade to 14.10 from 14.04 , apart from the reason that 14.04.02 is LTS.

Moreover everywhere I see the advertisement that "More smarter and faster than ever, Ubuntu 14.10"

Comment: What features of Ubuntu you usually use?
(Development? )

Comment: I avoid non LTS simply because upgrading every 6 months can be very troublesome especially if you use ubuntu for development. Upgrades bring new software but can break old and sometimes needed software. With LTS versions you often avoid these issues.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. You will have to examine the differences between support and what your intentions of use are, and make a decision on your own which upgrade path is better for you.

Comment: @ubuntu99: yes I am using ubuntu for development , I basically do web, java as well as android apps.

Comment: Stick to LTS version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have version 14.10 at the office and version 14.04.2 at home and I see no difference whatsoever. However, version 14.10 does have a different kernel, which might prove useful if you have some hardware problems in version 14.04. Other changes, from what I read, are minor.

If you are not having hardware problems, I'd say that the reason why you shouldn't upgrade are: (i) 14.04 is LTS (but you said it already) and (ii) generally I find it better (from personal experience) to stay one release behind. The reason for that is that this way you give some time for bugs to be fixed and you avoid some headaches that are related to these bugs. Other than those reasons, I can see no good reason to support (or not) this decision.

Comment: The kernel from 14.10 is available for hardware enabling in 14.04 now, as is the newer Xorg.